# how to use .htaccess in laravel

Tags: laravel

I made a directory in my host:

```
www.mysite.com/test/
```

and I've copied my laravel folders inside it. but when I call that url on my browser it show me this:

[image]

I think I should make a `.htaccess` .

Comment: good question, I also search about this. But, can't find the solution.

Comment: Use this URL : www.mysite.com/test/public

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample for my case and your case:-

My Case:-

```
URL Before .htaccess www.xyz.com/public/index.php
URL After .htaccess www.xyz.com

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* public/index.php [L]
```

Your Case:-

```
URL Before .htaccess www.xyz.com/test/public/index.php
URL After .htaccess www.xyz.com

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* test/public/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel app is inside /public folder, which also already has a .htaccess: `mysite.com/public/test`

What you can do is symlink the `project/public` folder to the public directory. For example:

```
ln -s /path/to/project/public /var/www
```

Now you should be able to see the app on `mysite.com/test`.

[This article](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e#.meoipb0aq) on deploying a Laravel 5 application might help.

Answer (score 0):

The 
    .htaccess 
file is already existed in public folder what you need to configure is your server

for Linux on terminal execute :

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo vi myapp.conf
```

Add/Modify these lines to suit your server

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myapp.localhost.com
DocumentRoot "/home/vagrant/projects/myapp/public"
<Directory "/home/vagrant/projects/myapp/public">
AllowOverride all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Save the file, then continue below.

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available$ cd ../sites-enabled
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ sudo ln -s ../sites-available/myapp.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

And for Windows Servers inside your Laravel root folder add web.config file and write these codes inside it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="index.php" />
            <add value="default.aspx" />
            <add value="Default.htm" />
            <add value="Default.asp" />
            <add value="index.htm" />
            <add value="index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script" />
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/public/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

)

Comment: What if he doesn't have SSH access? @nour

Comment: @vijayrana Do you mean shared hosting ?

Comment: @vijayrana I got it check my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/38844990/4439978

Answer (score -2):

Create an `.htaccess` file on your laravel's root directory. This is to access it without the "public" on the url

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```