# how to install laravel inside an addon domain

Tags: php, laravel

I have an `addon` domain like this :

```
/public_html/mysite
```

Site is available from the following address:

```
www.mysite.com
```

now I want to install `laravel` on this `addon` site.

I've copied all folders insdie `mysite` directory :

but when I enter `www.mysite.com` on my browser it shows content of my laravel project :

[image]

**solved:**

[How to install laravel inside an addon domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592493/how-to-install-laravel-inside-an-addon-domain)

Comment: I've seen some topics before.

Comment: I've already answered your question there :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841983/how-to-use-htaccess-in-laravel/38843401#38843401

Comment: These should all be a folder back, and anything in the public folder should be in this folder here.

Comment: a folder back is main my site and have another content files ! can I do handle this by `.htaccess` ?

Comment: If you can change your vhost then do that (answer mentioned above). If you can't, then put it a folder back, into another new folder, then modify the index.php to look in the correct place, change the 2 references to bootstrap.

Comment: @Nour Yasein  I can not access to server .

Comment: @S.M_Emamian Did you solved it? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @vijayrana
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592493/how-to-install-laravel-inside-an-addon-domain

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways you can install laravel inside an addon domain. Here is one of the easiest ways to do it.

1. Go to your CPanel and open **Softaculous Apps Installer**.
2. Look for Laravel Installer and open it. Carefully select the addon domain where you want to install Laravel.
3. Click Install. If there was no previous install then it would take 3-4 seconds.
4. Now go to the File Manager and open that specific domain folder. You will see All the laravel files there.

Now if you have an **existing project** that you want to upload on this domain simply make a zip file of your project and upload & extract inside this domain folder.

**ONE LAST THING**

When you install Laravel using Softaculous Apps Installer you get a redirect from domain to /public. To resolve this open index.php file (Not the one inside the public folder, one that is outside). Remove all the code from it and just paste the code given below.

```
<?php
header('Location: public/');
?>
```

And that is it. This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a shared hosting you're using if yes then :

Put the content of public (L5) directly on public_html (be aware of don't overwrite the .htaccess file accidentally)
Now in 
then modify your index.php and your bootstrap.php and it will work just fine

Comment: post your Q as a comment. yes.

Comment: I've updated the answer ) and I can't comment that's why it turned to an answer ))

Comment: in `public_html` there are another content.

Comment: I know that's correct but to do a Laravel installation on a shared hosting I am almost sure it's the only way but like I said be aware of overwriting the .htaccess accidentally