# How to install laravel inside an addon domain

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

my project name is `yadavarpro`.

I created a `yadavarpro` folder behind of `public_html` and I copied all folders except `public`.

(I could not upload the image on StackOverflow!)

like this image:

http://yadavarpro.com/1.JPG

I created another `yadavarpro` folder inside `public_html` and copy all contents of `public` folder.

like this image:

http://yadavarpro.com/2.JPG

but my site show a white screen. I think I should change bootstrap configure. 
But I don't know.

http://yadavarpro.com/

Comment: you have to copy all contents of public folder directly to your public_html folder including .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved:

edit `index.php` inside `public_html/yadavarpro`:

use:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../../yadavarpro/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../yadavarpro/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

instead of:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need the public directory and all it's contents. As long as the addon domain points to the public laravel directory then it should work ok.

Comment: what does mean `public directory`?  `public_html` or `public `folder? I should copy all thing of my `public` folder to `public_html`?

Comment: I mean the public directory in the laravel application. You'll probably end up removing public_html and pointing the webroot of the domain to public/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is highly unorthodox, but you may trick laravel into accepting it (probably not but worth trying).

I'll refer to 2 important files in the laravel boot procedure: the [index](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/index.php) and the [app bootstrapper](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/bootstrap/app.php)

Basically in the index there's a 2 references to `__DIR__."../bootstrap"` (one for the autoloader and one for the app) which you need to alter to find the actual bootstrap location. In your current structure that's probably: `__DIR__."../yadavarpro/bootstrap"` if I understand it correctly.

In the app bootstrapper you need to do:

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
$app->instance("path.public",__DIR__."../../public_html"); //Basically overwrite the public path with whatever the correct one is.
```

This assumes that whoever needs to get the public path they will always get it via `public_path` or `app()->make("path.public")` and never assume that it is just `base_path("public")` however it's unlikely this assumption is never made in any part of Laravel or any module within so beware.